# Autostart script not working in Qtile on Manjaro

Tags: python, manjaro, window-manager

I have Qtile installed on Manjaro, and in the `config.py` I have it set to run and autostart script `autostart.sh`. However, when I start Qtile it does not run, I get no errors or anything. I have to run the script manually every time I start Qtile.

This is what I have in my `config.py`:

```
from libqtile import hook
import os
import subprocess

@hook.subscribe.startup_once
def autostart():
    home = os.path.expanduser('~/.config/qtile/autostart.sh')
    subprocess.call([home])
```

This is what I have in my `autostart.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --output HDMI1 --left-of eDP1 &
nitrogen --restore &
picom -f &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run: `chmod +x autostart.sh`